# How to calculate the Fourier coefficients accurately using numerical method?

Tags: numerical-methods, fourier-series, numerical-calculus

If a function $f(x)$ is $2\pi$ periodic, we may calculate its Fourier coefficients
$$a_n = \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}f(x)e^{inx}dx$$
by numerical integration.
However, when $f(x)$ is smooth enough (such as $f(x) = \cos(\cos(x))$) and thus $a_n$ decays fast, the relative error of the calculation will be very big.

I think this is because when doing numerical integration, we are adding some $f(x_k)e^{inx_k}$, which are relatively big, to get a small number $a_n$. Is there any method to avoid this?

Comment: To get the first $n$ coefficients, apply the FFT with $2n$ or $4n$ sample points and throw away the higher order coefficients that more strongly accumulate the error you describe. Otherwise, the cure for catastrophic cancellation is to use a higher precision with some multi-precision number type.

Comment: It is a good exercise to compute everything accurately, but is there a specific application that requires that the small coefficients are computed very accurately? For example if small numbers are added to large numbers, it doesn't matter if the small numbers have large relative errors.